# Android: high quality image resizing / scaling

Tags: android, algorithm, image, scaling

I need to scale down images coming from a Network stream without losing quality.

I am aware of this solution [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue) but it is too coarse - `inSampleSize` is an integer and does not allow finer control over the resulting dimensions. That is, I need to scale images to specific h/w dimensions (and keeping aspect ratio).

I dont mind having a DIY bicubic/lancoz algorithm in my code but I cant find any examples that would work on Android as they all rely on Java2D (JavaSE).

EDIT:
Ive attached a quick source. The original is 720x402 HD screen capture. Please ignore the top 2 thumbnails. The top large image is resized automatically by android (as part of layout) to about 130x72. It is nice and crisp. The bottom image is resized with API and has severe artifacting

[image]

I've also tried using the BitmapFactory and, as I said earlier, it has two problems - no way to scale to exact size and the scaled image is blurry.

Any ideas on how to fix the artifcating?

Thanks, S.O.!

```
    package qp.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class imgview extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a000001570402);
        Bitmap resized = getResizedBitmap(original, 130);
        //Bitmap resized = getResizedBitmap2(original, 0.3f);
        System.err.println(resized.getWidth() + "x" + resized.getHeight());

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewFullManual);
        image.setImageBitmap(resized);

    }

    private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();

        int height = bm.getHeight();

    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    float scaleWidth = newWidth;

    float scaleHeight = scaleWidth / aspect;        // yeah!

    // create a matrix for the manipulation

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth / width, scaleHeight / height);

    // recreate the new Bitmap

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

        bm.recycle();

        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap getResizedBitmap2(Bitmap bm, float scale) {

    /*    float aspect = bm.getWidth() / bm.getHeight();

        int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scale);
        int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scale);
*/
        // original image is 720x402 and SampleSize=4 produces 180x102, which is
        // still too large

        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inSampleSize = 4;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a000001570402, bfo);
    }

}
```

And the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<!-- <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="hullo" android:background="#00ff00"
    />
     -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewThumbAuto"
            android:layout_width="130dip" android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:src="@drawable/a000001570402"  />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewThumbManual"
            android:layout_width="130dip" android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:src="@drawable/a000001570402"  
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ImageViewThumbAuto"
            />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewFullAuto" android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="169dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a000001570402"
            android:layout_below="@id/ImageViewThumbAuto"
            />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewFullManual" android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="169dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a000001570402"
            android:layout_below="@id/ImageViewFullAuto"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i dont think the top image is actually 130px wide. http://icons-search.com/img/fasticon/fast_emoticons_lnx.zip/fast_emoticons_lnx-Icons-128X128-smile_1.png-128x128.png is 128 px wide....

Comment: check out [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) about decoding images .

Comment: Hi! Faced same issue, did you find solution?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `BitmapFactory.Options` with `BitmapFactory.decode` function(s),
using **`inDensity`** and **`inTargetDensity`**

Example: you have **1600x1200** size of image and want to resize to **640x480**
then `'inDensity'=5` and `'inTargetDensity'=2` (1600x2 equal to 640x5).

Hoping this help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces nearest neighbor downscaling. As I figured out, to keep bicubic downscaling, only inSampleSize is allowed to be changed.

Answer (score 8):

The top large image is simply scaled down to 450px by the layout so no artifacts.

The artifacts of the bottom large image result from scaling it down to 130px wide and then up again to about 450px by the layout. So the artifacts are made by your scaling. Try

```
Bitmap resized = getResizedBitmap(original, 450);
```

in your code and it should be fine. However, you need to adapt that to the actuall screen width of the phone either.

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, good downscaling algorithm (not nearest neighbor like) consists of 2 steps:

1. downscale using ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** as close as possible to the resolution that you need but not less than it
2. get to the exact resolution by downscaling a little bit using ***Canvas::drawBitmap()***

Here is detailed explanation how SonyMobile resolved this task: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Here is the source code of SonyMobile scale utils: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/image-scaling-code-example-for-android/

Comment: unfortunately, those links are no longer available.