# Resizing a bitmap that automatically rotates

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, autorotate

I have a code in which I call the gallery to select an image that i show in a imageview . This works fine and maintains the aspect ratio.
The problem is when the image size is larger than 2048 x 2048
I am using this code when it is the case:

> uriIsNowAbitmap =
>   MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
>   selectedImageUri);
>
> ```
>               //...
>
>           int height = uriIsNowAbitmap.getHeight();
>           int width = uriIsNowAbitmap.getWidth();
>
>           if ((width>=2048)||(height>=2048)) {
>
>               int newheight  = height/10; // height in pixels
>               int newwidth = width/10; // width in pixels    
>               Bitmap avatarScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(uriIsNowAbitmap,  newwidth, newheight, true);
>
>               previewNewAvatar.setImageBitmap(avatarScaled);
> ```
>
> }

also works correctly, but with a problem. The images are not of the type shown rotated landscape

to try to explain, I put this example. This is the picture of the gallery:

[image]

when I select the picture and assign it to the imageview is shown rotated:

[image]

I do not understand why. I've tried a thousand ways and have read a lot of information about resize, i have read threads and sample code for this website ([Android: high quality image resizing / scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207562/android-high-quality-image-resizing-scaling)) and and many more... but nothing helps.
The intention is to show in this way ...*make it with photoshop* :)

[image]

I appreciate any help, took many hours trying to fix it

Regards

Comment: Did you managed to fix it? I have the same problem.

Comment: How did you managed this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to detect the orientation change, and when you detect a change to landscape orientation you just rotate your bitmap accordingly. You will have to declare your Bitmap avatarScaled as a global variable in order to access it in the onConfigurationChanged() method below:

Use the onConfigurationChanged method of Activity to detect change in orientation. See the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(avatarScaled, 0, 0, avatarScaled.getWidth(),
                                     avatarScaled.getHeight(), matrix, true);
previewNewAvatar.setImageBitmap(rotated);
} 
}
```

You also have to edit the appropriate element in your manifest file to include the android:configChanges Just see the code below:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: unfortunately the solution you propose is not working properly because the same situation persists. Thank you very much for your interest. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MiguelC can you post more code please, preferably the entire activity in which this problem arises?