# Android, Java: Scaling .PNG results in low quality

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-scaling

I am creating this game for Android with Java. I am using this code: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html for resizing Bitmaps, I am using .PNG format on all my images. It works really well except that the Bitmaps  quality drops quite a lot, even when I scale it down from a larger image. Is this solvable?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: I use the exact code that's in the provided link (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: See this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207562/android-high-quality-image-resizing-scaling

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code.

> ```
>  public static Bitmap shrinkBitmap(String p_file, int p_width, int p_height)
> {
>     BitmapFactory.Options m_bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>     m_bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
>     Bitmap m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p_file, m_bmpFactoryOptions);
>     int m_heightRatio =
>             (int) Math.ceil(m_bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / (float) p_height);
>     int m_widthRatio =
>             (int) Math.ceil(m_bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / (float) p_width);
>     if (m_heightRatio > 1 || m_widthRatio > 1)
>     {
>         if (m_heightRatio > m_widthRatio)
>         {
>             m_bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = m_heightRatio;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             m_bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = m_widthRatio;
>         }
>     }       
>     m_bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
>     m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p_file, m_bmpFactoryOptions);
>     return m_bitmap;
> }
> ```

EDITED:
Here i have tried out other way also.
Can you please let me know how you are scaling `.PNGs` so that i can get the idea.

Comment: I'm not really using ImageViews, is there any benefits doing so and wouldn't it be quite a lot of them if you have many images? (I might got the idea wrong, but I wasn't really sure what ImageView was so I googled and got: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/)