# out of memory in android while opening a customized dialog view?

Tags: android

on click opening a dialog view it giving an out of memory? In dialog i have two images in it and 1 image button, even the  size of image is 40 50kb.

```
04-15 10:11:07.085: E/dalvikvm-heap(29896): Out of memory on a 16384016-byte allocation.
04-15 10:11:07.085: I/dalvikvm(29896): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-15 10:11:07.085: I/dalvikvm(29896):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c51460 self=0x12938
04-15 10:11:07.085: I/dalvikvm(29896):   | sysTid=29896 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1075008808
04-15 10:11:07.085: I/dalvikvm(29896):   | schedstat=( 1269958584 831219251 1666 ) utm=105 stm=21 core=0
04-15 10:11:07.085: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
04-15 10:11:07.090: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-15 10:11:07.095: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
04-15 10:11:07.095: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
04-15 10:11:07.095: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-15 10:11:07.095: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-15 10:11:07.095: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
04-15 10:11:07.100: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-15 10:11:07.100: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
04-15 10:11:07.100: I/dalvikvm(29896):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
```

Comment: The size of the image is 50kb on disk.  How big is it when loaded?  What resolution, colour depth and format is the image?

Comment: are you trying to run in device or emulator ? Post your code

Comment: Not sure if image scaling will help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7245230/755804

Comment: can you post us your code snippets.

Comment: yes the size is 50 kb but know i reduce the size more, and in device its not working, Thanks.